# Where to find/download "php7activescript.dll"?

Tags: php, dll

I want to upgrade from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7 (on Windows), but the site http://pecl4win.php.net/ is down (and from previous questions, down for months). So I cant download "php7activescript.dll". Is there any place I can download the "php7activescript.dll" from? I Googled and searched but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, it does not exist.

ActiveScript was moved to [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/PHPScript), way back in history (PHP 5.0.1).

ActiveScript has never had an official release, and has not been ported to PHP 7.